# How do I put welcome text before username in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a simple flutter application.

I have a problem on how do I put text before the value got called form the api

this is the output that I want to achieve

```
Hello, $username
Tittle : $adsTitle

****
Hello, Jack
Tittle : Make A wish
```

```
 Profile profile = snapshot.data[index];
                      return Card(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget> [
                             Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Center(child:user == null ? Text('') : Text((user), style: 
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 30) )),
                                Center(
                                child: Text('${profile.adsTitle}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: 
                                mainColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ),
                          ],
                         ),
                        ),
                      );
```

How do I put text `Hello` at the `child: Center(child:user == null ? Text('') : Text((user), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),`

and `Tittle` at the  `Center(child: Text('${profile.adsTitle}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: mainColor),),),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation

e.g.

```
Text("Hello $user")
```

or

```
Text('Title ${profile.adsTitle}')
```

You can also use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget for that.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
Text("Hello $user");
```